# Navigation Controller with translucent effect

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

My app have a problem with navigation controller. After I set a theme with chameleon and login with facebook. My app segue to initialView, but navigation controller appearance is wrong.

[image: wrong]

The correct is

[image: correct]

I try to define barstyle, translucent, background color and nothing.

Ps: The icons in first pic are blue because I set bartintcolor of navigationbar.

So, what I can do?

Comment: Can you please post the code where you are setting the `UINavigationController` bar color?

Comment: For a first moment, before facebook login:  Chameleon.setGlobalThemeUsingPrimaryColor(nil, withSecondaryColor: nil, andContentStyle: UIContentStyle.Dark) and after facebook login is correct: Chameleon.setGlobalThemeUsingPrimaryColor(myColor, withContentStyle: .Contrast)

Comment: There are tons of questions posted on SO regarding `translucentEffect`, so please query and refer them first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my snippet which should work in `Swift 3`.

```
    navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
    navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 0.113725, green: 0.450980, blue: 0.890196, alpha: 1)// Set to any colour
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to do

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(nil, forBarMetrics:UIBarMetrics.Default)
navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = false
navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = nil
```

Comment: This happens: https://s15.postimg.org/t19fuq3kr/Screen_Shot_2016_11_18_at_16_29_20.png . I try to define backgroundColor again and nothing. Everything is white now.

Comment: Sorry i forget to put one line, i've edited the answer

Comment: Nothing yet. All white... :/